# Method that change the style of an element from another file

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, methods

I'm making a PWA and there I have a MenuBar that appears in all the pages of the PWA, but I wanna change the MenuBar icon acording to the page that i am at the moment. I'll show you pictures to see how it is:

[image: wrong home icon in menubar]

and I wanna make it look like this:

[image: wanted home icon in menubar]

this is the MenuBar code:

```
<template>
    <nav>
        <div class="divMenuOpcoes">
            <div><router-link to="/"><img src="../assets/homeIcon2.png"></router-link></div>
            <div><router-link to="/criarpostagem"><img src="../assets/addIcon.png"></router-link></div>
            <div><img src="../assets/newsIcon.png"></div>
            <div><img src="../assets/userIcon.png" v-on:click="redirectPerfilLogin"></div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</template>

<script>
import { useStore } from 'vuex'

export default {
    name: 'MenuBar',
    setup() {

        const store = useStore()
        const redirectPerfilLogin = () => {

            const token = store.getters.getToken
            if(!token){
                window.location.href='/login'
            }else {
                store.dispatch('validateSessionAction', token)
                store.commit('SET_SWAP', true)
                window.location.href='/perfil'
            }
        }
        return {redirectPerfilLogin}
    }
}

</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
    @import "../assets/stylesheets/pallete.scss";

    nav{
        bottom: 0;
        position: fixed;
        display: flex;

        height: 70px;
        width: 100%;

        background-color: $colorBranca;
        border-top: 1px solid $colorCinza;
    }   

    .divMenuOpcoes{
        display: flex;
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 400px;
        margin: 10px 20px;

        & div{
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;

            height: 100%;
            flex: 1;
            
            & img{
                display: block;

                margin: auto;
                height: 30px;
                padding: 10px 15px;

                cursor: pointer;
            }
        }
    }   
</style>
```

I already have all the blue images uped to the project with the same name of ther others, but with 2 in the end of their names. Thank You!

Comment: You should add a mounted method to each component that is connected to a router link.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the following solution. The variable icons in the data block is reactive. This means that whenever it's value changes the linked items in the template are updated. (in this case the image sources.

I added a watcher that looks out for route changes. Whenever the route is changed the according sources are updated.

```
<template>
    <nav>
        <div class="divMenuOpcoes">
            <div><router-link to="/"><img :src="../assets/" + this.icons['/'] + ".png"></router-link></div>
            <div><router-link to="/criarpostagem"><img src="../assets/" + this.icons['/criarpostagem'] + ".png"></router-link></div>
            <div><img src="../assets/newsIcon.png"></div>
            <div><img src="../assets/userIcon.png" v-on:click="redirectPerfilLogin"></div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</template>

<script>
import { useStore } from 'vuex'
export default {
    name: 'MenuBar',
    data: {
        icons: {
            "/": "homeIcon2",
            "/criarpostagem": "addIcon"
        }
    }
    setup() {
        const store = useStore()
        const redirectPerfilLogin = () => {
            const token = store.getters.getToken
            if(!token){
                window.location.href='/login'
            }else {
                store.dispatch('validateSessionAction', token)
                store.commit('SET_SWAP', true)
                window.location.href='/perfil'
            }
        }
        return {redirectPerfilLogin}
    },
    watch:{
        $route (to, from){
            this.icons[to] = this.icons[to] + '2'
            this.icons[from] = this.icons[from].replace('2', '')
        }
    } 
}
</script>
```

I haven't tested this code myself, but please let me know if it works.

Comment: I tested it, and it didn't work, but I don't know why. I had never used the watch before so I still don't know what is wrong.